# Android ndk-r9 compiler optimization issues

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, arm

I recently switched to using Android ndk-r9 and am having some difficulty with my app that seems to be related to compiler optimization.  I have the following function:

```
int GetTouchPos(GTouchEvents * pEvents, GPointF * pPos, int * pButton = 0)
{
    int                count    = 0;
    GTouchEvent    *    pEvent;        

    if (pEvents->GetCount(&count) == GResult_Ok)
    {
        GDebugLog((GS("GetTouchPos: count = %d"), count));

        if (pEvents->GetEvent(0, &pEvent) == GResult_Ok)
        {
            pEvent->GetTapPos(pPos);

            if (pButton)
            {
                pEvent->GetButton(pButton);
            }

            pEvent->Release();
        }
    }

    return(count);
}
```

If I build my project and run it, the call to GDebugLog formats and logs the value of the variable 'count'.  When I do this, 'count' is 1 and my app works correctly.  However if I comment out the GDebugLog line (and make NO other changes), when I run my app, it no longer works.  In the function GTouchEvents::GetCount, I also am logging what it is returning and the value is always correctly '1'.  Also, I log the return from the call to the function above (i.e. GetTouchPos).  When the GDebugLog line is present, the logged return value is the correct value '1'.  However when I comment out the GDebugLog call, the logged return value is a seemingly random number, which looks suspiciously like an uninitialized variable.

Note that this all works with our without the GDebugLog line when I was using r8b.  Also note that if I turn optimization off, this code works perfectly using r9 whether the debugging line is present or not.  Also note that this behavior only presents itself when compiling for the ARM processor.  The version I build for x86 works without problem.

Am I doing something questionable here that is causing the optimizer to generate incorrect code?

Can anyone shed some light on what might be happening?

Thanks.

Comment: How do you turn optimization off? See NDK changes to see if something sounds related http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html#Revisions. Try to create a small confined code to generate same problem, information you've provided isn't enough.

Comment: If you have debuggable set to 'true' in the manifest, then when you build the NDK, I believe that all optimization is disabled.  I am not sure how to control it manually, or what optimizations I would need to turn off to get this to work.  I can of course introduce code that makes this work with optimization on, but I am really worried that there are other places in my code where this happens that I have not discovered.  For now I guess I am going to stick with r8b which does not exhibit this problem.  Thanks.

Comment: Change the code to `if (pEvents->GetEvent(0, &pEvent) != GResult_Ok) return 0;` and is the value consistent?  It maybe that `GetEvent` touches the variable when it returns an error.  You maybe reading the event too soon.  Is this multi-threaded?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I do not believe that the GetEvent ever returns failure, however.  Anyway, the problem occurs when it is successful.  What appears to be happening is that the value being returned from GetCount (and stored in count) is, due to optimization, not being returned by properly GetTouchPos.  Adding the debug line makes it work.  I do have a separate thread that handles the display, but it does not make calls to retrieve events and that thread and the main thread (which is the one that runs this code) lock each other out.

Comment: Then add the objdump of the function from two compilers.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by adding the objdump, can you explain?  Thanks.

Comment: use "arm-linux-androideabi-objdump -d" on produced object file, check that specific function. You make a claim that compiler optimization removes something. Next step then is to prove that you are right.

Comment: @JohnGaby: Which compiler are you using for ARM? Do you set optimization level or optimization flags in your `Android.mk` or `Appliation.mk`?

Comment: I have a number of phones and tablets and it fails on all of them.  I am using the default optimization which is set based on whether debugging is set in the manifest (I am not really sure how to control the optimization manually).  For now, I am sticking with the r8b release (which works) as I have not had the time to investigate this further.